# Runtime Error: Java gateway process exited when using Pyspark

Tags: python, java, apache-spark, pyspark, environment-variables

I am using Pycharm with Python 3. When I create a Spark session, I get the following error :

```
RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

I have been spending the 3 last hours trying to debug this, modifying environment variables and all that... I am still stuck.

Here is the code I wrote :

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
         
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Practice').getOrCreate()
```

Here are the environment variables :

[image]

Here is the whole error prompt :

```
    C:\Users\sewa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\sewa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4\main.py 
La syntaxe du nom de fichier, de r�pertoire ou de volume est incorrecte.
Failed to find Spark jars directory.
You need to build Spark before running this program.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sewa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local[*]').appName('Practice').getOrCreate()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sewa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4\venv\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 269, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sewa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4\venv\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 483, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "C:\Users\sewa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4\venv\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 195, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "C:\Users\sewa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4\venv\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 417, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sewa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4\venv\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 106, in launch_gateway
    raise RuntimeError("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

Please help !

Comment: Hey @swealevrai, did you try setting the environment variable in the code, before initializing the Spark Session, to ensure java is correctly installed? For example: ```os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "path/to/java"```

Comment: [*Apache Hadoop 3.3 and upper supports Java 8 and Java 11 (runtime only)*](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP/Hadoop+Java+Versions). What version did you pick? Java 19. Also, *Failed to find Spark jars directory.*

Comment: @KevinBarranco I just tried, still got the same error message :/

Comment: @ElliotFrisch it is Java 19.0.2

Comment: So that's the issue. You need to install Java 8 or 11 and then point to this new installation. Then it should work.

Comment: @KevinBarranco I switched to Java 11, still not working... Maybe there is a python file related to spark where I can directly enter the path to Java ? So it doesn't have to look for it

Comment: I see. Well, some of the things you can do to make sure everything is correct: 1. Make sure the variables are accessible by running `echo ${SPARK_HOME}` and `echo ${JAVA_HOME}` on cmd, to make sure it's pointing to your new Java installation; 2. Try the same with Java 8. I always had issues with Spark in Windows and Java 8 was my way out. 3. Double check your Spark jar folder and its env var. Make sure it's pointing to the jar and all files are there. As Elliott mentioned above, one of the error messages is saying the Spark jars were not found.

Comment: @sewalevrai try the steps in this gist https://gist.github.com/d4rkc0de/0fe1307fc70178398a9d55c0fb2c91df